# how to Scan with Samsung SCX-3200 over network

Tags: 12.04, networking, samsung, scanner

Printer is detected and is working over my wireless network, but i don't know how to detect scanner. Simple-scan doesn't see the device...

Comment: Did you follow [this](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ScanningHowTo#Sharing_a_Scanner_Over_a_Network) guide?

Answer (score 2):

Try to use the instructions and repository of http://www.bchemnet.com/suldr/index.html
I used it to install a  CLX-3185FN.

1.add the repo:

`sudo sh -c 'echo "deb http://www.bchemnet.com/suldr/ debian extra" >> /etc/apt/sources.list'`

`sudo wget -O - http://www.bchemnet.com/suldr/suldr.gpg | sudo apt-key add - && sudo apt-get update`

2.install

`sudo apt-get install samsungmfp-configurator-qt4 samsungmfp-data samsungmfp-network`

Comment: Thanks, this worked for me! One tip — the detection and interaction with the SCX-3400W requires being able to [receive UDP packets on an arbitrary high port](http://www.bchemnet.com/suldr/forum/index.php?topic=105.0), so the first step in all of this should be to disable the firewall. Also, while the scanner might be detected by the netdiscovery tool while it's in standby, some applications (like Simple Scan) won't see it unless it's out of standby.